# Disable shipping method on Dokan if the store is closed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

Is there any way to use this code for disabling a specific shipping method? For example, if I want to use a "flat rate" method, and if the store closes, I want this method not to appear.

I tried to replace the is_purchasable hook with woocommerce_load_shipping_methods with instance id "6", but that didn't work.

Below is the code that is working for disabling a purchase, but not the shipping method.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'prefix_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
function prefix_woocommerce_is_purchasable( $is_purchasable, $product ) {

// Get the store id.
$store_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $product->get_id() );

// Get the store info.
$store_info = dokan_get_store_info( $store_id );

// Get the store time enabled or not.
$is_dokan_store_time_enabled = $store_info['dokan_store_time_enabled'];

// If the store time is enabled, check whether the store is open or not.
// Else the store is open.
if ( 'yes' === $is_dokan_store_time_enabled ) {
    $is_purchasable = dokan_is_store_open( $store_id );     
} else  {
    $is_purchasable = true;
}

return $is_purchasable;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code in the child theme's **functions.php** file.

```
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages', 
'dokan_custom_split_shipping_packages' );
```

Dokan sipping will be disabled by using this code. Admin will manage shipping from the backend (WooCommerce Shipping)

Comment: We have tried this with the Stripe Connect configuration. In Dokan settings we have an admin commission, and configured shipping fees go to admin. After checkout, the vendors get the correct payment based on the products sold. The admin gets the correct commission through the "collected fees" in stripe. But we cannot find out if the shipping fee gets charged, and if it does, where it goes. It's not showing up under "Collected fees" on the admin stripe connect, nor in the vendor payments. Yet the woocommerce order shows the fee is charged.